# Three-way manova or separate anovas?

Tags: anova, variance, statistical-power, manova, kruskal-wallis-test

I have three independent catagorial variables and two dependent continuous scale variables, so I want to compare means across these three independent catagorial variables.

I think here the best choice would be three way manova, but I'm facing problem with my dependent continuous variables for example one of the dependent continuous variables was not normally distributed so I had to run kruskal wallis test, or the second dependent variable violated the assumption of homogeneity of variance.

So I decided to run multiple separate anovas or kruskal wallis tests, because it's not possible to run three way manova.

Is this the best approach for this problem?

Comment: What makes you believe that the distribution of the predictor variables is an issue?

Comment: @mdewey I read it according to this site https://www.statisticssolutions.com/free-resources/directory-of-statistical-analyses/assumptions-of-the-factorial-anova/#:~:text=The%20factorial%20ANOVA%20has%20a,and%20(4)%20no%20multicollinearity.

Comment: I think you need to read that again as it is about the outcome variable not the predictors. It is wrong anyway it is not the distribution of the data but the distribution of the residuals from the model which matters.

Comment: @mdewey sorry I will correct my question, I mean my dependent variables are not normally distributed. I wrote it wrong

Comment: @mdewey is doing separate anovas the correct method?